# Is it possible to find additional key pairs resulting in the same address that I already control?

Tags: address, private-key, public-key, address-generation

I'm not really well versed in the necessary terminology to get the answer I need from searching.
As I understand, there are 2^160 possible addresses, and 2^256 possible private keys, so each address corresponds to roughly 2^(256-160)=2^96 private keys.

Let's say I generate a key pair and the corresponding address, how would one go about finding other key pairs that correspond to the same address if you already have at least 1 set of keys that generated that address? Is it possible?

Apologies if this has been answered already, I couldn't find the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, practically speaking.

A [P2PKH Bitcoin address](https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Pay-to-Pubkey_Hash) is computed as `RIPEMD160(SHA256(publickey))`. Since public keys are unique, to find another keypair that results in the same address, you're essentially trying to find a hash collision on SHA256 or RIPEMD160, which is [extremely difficult](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47809/why-havent-any-sha-256-collisions-been-found-yet).

The most "efficient" way to find such a collision would be to iterate over the entire private key space.

Comment: Searching for another input that has the same hash as a given input is technically called a "2nd preimage", and it is indeed intractable (needs ~2^160 trials). A collision is something else: namely looking for two inputs that hash to the same thing, without one of the two being given already.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.